# How pass angularjs array value into php function as a variable?

Tags: php

I have the code which return json response but I don't know how pass the that value in php function.

**Code:**

```
 <div class="container"  ng-controller="askbyctrl" >
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="q in qa.data" >
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col.sm.12" >
                <div class="artist-data pull-left" style = "background-color:#BEB7B7;">
                    <div class="artst-pic pull-left">
                        <?php
                            function cache_image($id){
                                //replace with cache directory
                                $image_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\QA_UI\images';

                                $image_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/image/' + id;

                                //get the name of the file
                                $exploded_image_url = explode("/",$image_url);
                                $image_filename = 'id.jpg';
                                $exploded_image_filename = explode(".",$image_filename);
                                $extension = end($exploded_image_filename);
                                //make sure its an image
                                if($extension=="jpg") {
                                    //get the remote image
                                    $image_to_fetch = file_get_contents($image_url);
                                    if($image_to_fetch == '{"error":true,"details":"No image."}') {
                                        echo 'file not found';
                                    } else {
                                        //save it
                                        $local_image_file  = fopen($image_path.'/'.$image_filename, 'w+');
                                        chmod($image_path.'/'.$image_filename,0755);
                                        fwrite($local_image_file, $image_to_fetch);
                                        fclose($local_image_file);
                                        echo 'copied';  
                                    }
                                }
                            //}
                            ?>
                        <img ng-src="images/{{q.userID}}.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
```

Please see the code how can I pass the {{q.userID}} in php function..

Comment: had you thought about ajax

Comment: I don't have any idea how can I do this, if you have pleas tell me, I am new to angularJs and I don't know how can I use php code in angularJs.... I don't know I have to write seprate controller to take php code or I can use directly...

Comment: You cannot use server-side code inside client-side code. But your client, can call a resource with ajax calls, and that resource can contain documents rendered with php.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use ajax call in angularJs with php code...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way. PHP code is running on server side and angular-code in client-side, in browser. That is, when server returns compiled html to browser it has already done all php-code in that file.

If you want to check if image exists and then cache it, you can do it from angular for example with $http. Call with $http your backend-script, which does what you want, and then returns if it was success or not.

Comment: So how can I pass the object as variable in that php code because I have to pass the userID and take that image  and copy in my folder.....and this task is doing by php code which I have post.....please see and tell how can I do this....

Comment: You can't do it in ng-repeat. If you get that qa.data collection from server-side you can loop through that list before returning it to angular controller and there call that function.